# nodejs how to use findOne

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm new in nodejs. I'm useing mongodb and try to find a user by his name (username).
I'm using "findOne" method but for some reason it doesn't work, in the `console.log(admin)` it gives me null.
I hope you guys can help me.

**Code **

```
 router.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
 var name = req.body.username;
 var password = req.body.password;
 console.log(username);
 console.log(password);
  Admin.findOne({username:name}).then(admin =>{
      consol.log(admin);
     if(password == admin.username){
         console.log("worked");
     }else{
         res.json("Error!");
     }
  }).catch((err)=>{
     res.json(err);
 });    
});
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it doesn't work"?

Comment: You're not actually passing anything into `.findOne()`

Comment: Can you change it to Admin.findOne({'searchkey':'searchValue'})... where te key is  'username' and the value is the username you are trying to find

Comment: I have edited my question. @xan_z thats exactly what im trying to get

Comment: Okay, did that work? Also what are you using to connect to your DB? Mongoose?

Comment: well it didnt work. And yes. im using mongoose to connect to my DB

Answer (score 0):

For make a login API you also need to check `email` and `password`. For that I have a working API which I'm using and works fine. So just try to use this.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var promise = require('bluebird');

router.post('/login' , function(req , res){
   var data = req.body;
   return new promise(function(resolve , reject){
     var db = mongoClient.db();
     db.collection('uset').find({
        "email":data.email,
        "password":data.password
     }).toArray().then((result) => {
     if(result.length > 0){
       res.send({status:1 , message:"Success"});
     }
     else{
       res.send({status:0 , message:"No data found"});
    }
   });
  }).catch((err) => {
     console.log(err);
     res.send({status:0 , message:"Something went wrong." , methodName:'login'});
  })
});
```

**Note:** I have used **Bluebird** for promise.